# How could I get a rotated ellipse gradient in CSS3?

Tags: css, gradient, ellipse

I'm trying to get this gradient background (Made with Illustrator):

[image: What I want]

But all I get is this:

[image: What I get]

And its CCS3 code is this line:

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 5% 5%, #B90000, #2B0000);
```

How could I get the background I want?

Answer (score 4):

You can put the background in a rotated `before` pseudo-element.

I got the proportions through trial-and-error, and I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing that.

```css
    div {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 600px;
      height: 300px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
div::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      width: 250%;
      height: 250%;
      top: -40%;
      left: -50%;
      background: radial-gradient(
          ellipse 30% 20% at 30% 50%, 
          #B90000, 
          #2B0000);
      transform: rotate(30deg);
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Updated the answer to use the new code snippet editor/runner with your working code. I'm not seeing a native way in the `radial-gradient` syntax to do the rotation on an ellipse so I think this is still the best option. nice work! (8 years ago)